# PERL params from PHP submit/post

Tags: php, perl, apache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML form POST to a python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862788/html-form-post-to-a-python-script)

so I have a perl script that uses command line params, such as:

./gen_cards_md5.pl --num_cards=1000 --num_seeds=10

I'm trying to build a php web page to call the above script and pass it the params input on a form and submitted, this is roughly what I have:

```
echo <<<_END
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Generate Card Numbers Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Number of Cards: $num_cards<br />
    Number of Seeds: $num_seeds<br />
    <form method="post" action="gen_cards_md5.pl">
        Enter number of Cards to generate: <input type="text" name="num_cards" /> <br />
        Enter Number of Seeds: <input type="text" name="num_seeds" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" name="params" value="params"/>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
_END;
```

So you can probably guess where I am going with this, the php is calling the perl, but it's not passing the command line params.  Is there an easy way to see what (if anything is being passed), or does someone understand enough to tell me how I need to "format" the post to get it into the Perl script?  Note, I am just learning Python, and am really not even a hack at php and perl, so I'd really like to know how to see what's going on and be able to answer my own question, but in the interest of time, I just need to take this big honkin' perl script and get it to run from input through am HTML page.  Now that I've said that, I'm thinking to myself do I even need to make it a .php?  Am I just making things more complex by not going straight HTML to Perl?  I digress, to restate; given a working perl script that accepts command line arguments, how to I, through a web interface, pass the params it is expecting like in the command line?
TIA!
JP

Comment: Show us your perl code. The HTML looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post" action="somephpfile.php">
```

.

```
if (count($_POST) > 0){
     $num_cards = (isset($_POST['num_cards'])) ? (int)$_POST['num_cards'] : false;
     $num_seeds = (isset($_POST['num_seeds'])) ? (int)$_POST['num_seeds'] : false;
     if($num_cards !== false && $num_seeds !== false){
        exec("./gen_cards_md5.pl --num_cards={$num_cards} --num_seeds={$num_seeds}", $outputArray);
     }else{
         die('Number of cards or number of seeds not provided.');
     }
}
```